# how to trigger a batch file on a remote machine through command line

Tags: c#, joomla, cmd

i have a simple batch file that i would like to be able to trigger on a remote machine. Not as a scheduled task, but at will from cmd line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Set up [ssh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) on the remote machine and connect through that, than execute whatever you need.